# Add 1 day into existing date having dots in date

Tags: linux, bash, date, unix

**Input** I have date in the format of dots in it
example 2021.09.29

I want to **increment 1 day** into input date so that
**Output** will become 2021.09.30

I can able to do it if I have date which as dash or

```
date -d "2021-09-25 + 1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d"
```

I am getting invalid date error if I do

```
 date -d "2021.09.25 + 1 day" +"%Y.%m.%d"
```

Comment: This is an example of how GNU date is not as flexible as it likes to claim. BSD `date` would let you do something like `date -jv +1d -f %Y.%m.%d +%Y.%m.%d "2021.09.25"`. The `-f` option lets you specify the exact input format, rather than relying on GNU's broad but fixed set of options. (Though it would be nice if the output format could default to the input format, rather than requiring it to be specified twice.)

Answer (score 5):

Replacing the `.` with `-` is relatively straightforward:

```
$ d=2021.09.25
$ date -d "${d//./-/} + 1 day" +%Y.%m.%d
2021.09.26
```

Answer (score 0):

For count base on current day and at Unix/macOS

you can use this for tomorrow

```
date -v +1d +%Y.%m.%d
```

or yesterday

```
date -v -1d +%Y-%m-%d
```

Example

```
$ date -v +1d +%Y.%m.%d
2023.10.12
$ date -v -1d +%Y.%m.%d
2023.10.10
$ date +%Y.%m.%d
2023.10.11
```

Base on @chepner solutions for GNU

```
current_date=`date +%F`
next_date=`date -d "${current_date//./-/} + 1 day" +%F`
```